# how can display images (bmp or jpg) in graphics mode in c? just display

Tags: c

our teacher gives us a project in C as CAD that can draw same shapes and add text, and do same basic action with mouse and keyboard: drag, edit, filling, delete, delate all.... . all that are clear.
.
the problem is that, i need to create tools bar with photos (bmp, jpg ) as icons, to do same action like select, choose color, choose shape. i can't find clear idea in google, because we don't use stander graphics.h, we use other graphics.h that is popular in Chinese universities it  use InitGraphics() function that initialize an empty window, also I don't find enough information about this header file.
.
so, how i can display images in this window?

this is example for using this header file.

```
#include "graphics.h"

void Main(){ 
    InitGraphics();   /*Initialize to get an empty window*/
    MovePen(2,2);
    SetPenColor("green");
    DrawArc(1,1,150);
}
```

Comment: To help you, we will need more information about this graphics.h. Links to complete documentation and the full text of the header would really help.

Comment: this is link for this header file. 
[link](https://github.com/a-low-profile-team-of-zju/demo/blob/master/flowChart/libgraphics/graphics.h)

Comment: OK, I don't see any good way to do what you want without bypassing the abstraction imposed by this graphics.h. Since this is coursework, that might not be allowed. I suggest you ask your instructor the same question you've asked us.

Comment: (I do see a _bad_ way to draw raster images: decode the image file into memory, and then walk through the raster matrix pixel by pixel, issuing `MovePen`, `SetColor`, and `DrawLine` calls for every pixel. This would be painful to write and probably also much too slow. Don't do this unless your instructor specifically says this is how you should draw icons.)

Comment: it is allowed to use any libraries. I read about libjpeg, OpenCV, GTK... and others. but i cant understand the how to display images in graphics mode window that created by InitGraphics().
i same project i use:
`code`
#include "graphics.h"
#include "extgraph.h"
#include "genlib.h"
#include "simpio.h"
#include "random.h"
#include "strlib.h"
#include "conio.h"
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <stddef.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <olectl.h>
#include <mmsystem.h>
#include <wingdi.h>
#include <ole2.h>
#include <ocidl.h>
#include <winuser.h>
`code`

Comment: That's what I meant about bypassing the abstraction.  I don't see any way to do what you want without adding new functions to graphics.h and graphics.c (that would, e.g. let you access the HANDLE for the window), and I don't know if you're allowed to do that.  _You need to talk to your instructor about this._  I can't help you any further.